# How to define a structure in TypeScript?

Tags: java, json, angular, typescript

I have the following Json body structure. I wanna use this as a raw body for the POST Call in Angular 8, The input data coming from the Form and I wanna make it a JSON structure or some class structure in Type Script, but don't know how to achieve this:

```
{
    "valueMap": {
        "A1": {
            "price": 100,
            "remaining": 200
        },
        "A2": {
            "price": 100,
            "remaining": 200
        }
    }
}
```

I did the same thing in Java as:

```
class Request {
  Map<String, Amount> valueMap = new HashMap<>();
}

class Amount {
  double price;
  double remaining;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The syntax in Typescript is very close to the one written in Java. Here is an example of the interfaces you would use:

```js
interface Values {
  [K: string]: Amount
}


interface Amount {
  price: number
  remaining: number
}

const response: Values = {
  "Key1": {
    price: 1,
    remaining: 2,
  },
  "Key2": {
    price: 1,
    remaining: 2,
  }  
}
```

The trick to make this work is the `[K: string]` syntax, which enforces the index's type to be string.

One caveat to keep in mind is that the index may only be a `number` or `string`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create an object inside your component and directly use it while making API call

```
export class AppComponent  {
  valueMap = {};

  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    this.valueMap['A1'] = {price: 10, remaining: 20};
    this.valueMap['A2'] = {price: 10, remaining: 20};


    http.post('http://example.com', this.valueMap)
            .subscribe(() => {

    });
  }
}
```